# How search category by name or new attribute in magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, magento-2.0, category-attribute

How to get category by name and custom attribute programmatically?

Custom attribute is val_code. Custom code was added using InstallData

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in block file:

```
$collection = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToFilter('name', $value); // you can change name to your attribute code
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$nameValue = [name of your category];
$codeVal = [value of your code];

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$category = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')- >getCollection()->addFieldToSelect('entity_id')->addAttributeToSelect('name')->addAttributeToFilter('name',array('like'=>'%'.$nameValue.'%'))->addAttributeToFilter('val_code',$codeVal);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below code.

inject below collection Factory

```
\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryCollection
```

then get category collection

```
public function getCategoryCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->_categoryCollection->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('custom_attribute', '1');

        return $collection;
    }
```

Then call get the category name using below function.

```
getCustomAttribute()
```